# Prolog - printing function beginner

Tags: prolog

Only just started learning prolog so bear with me guys. 
I'm just dabbling in a little recursion, want to make a function which repeats a string N amount of times.

Here's my code thus far:

```
printn(N,X):-
    N is N-1,
    write(X),
    N > 0,
    printn(N,X).
```

I'm just getting false returned, could someone explain? 
Thank you

****EDIT****
**Working Code**

```
printn(N,X):-
    M is N-1,
    print(X),
    N > 0,
    nl,
    printn(M,X).
```

Comment: I've figured out my problem, Variables become instantiated as the computation proceeds, and then de-instantiated
on backtracking, but you can’t assign a new value to a variable that already has a  value.
So the predicate N is N-1 will simply fail if N is already bound to a number, and terminate your program with an error if it is not. N = N-1 will also not do anything
.

Comment: The above code is not working because you don't have a base case, it prints what you need to print but it does not succeed...

Comment: Note that recursion is most useful for dealing with recursive (data) structures. For example, a list in Prolog is a recursively defined data structure. A simple integer, on the other hand, is not. There are usually better ways to do things if you just need a counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print something a number of times, you can use `forall` and `between` like this:

> print "foo" three times

```
?- forall(between(1, 3, _), format("foo\n")).
foo
foo
foo
true.
```

This is the cleanest way to get a side effect a number of times (explicit printing is a side effect).

If you really insist to use recursion for this, consider using [`succ/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=succ/2) to count down to zero, then fail:

```
do_n(Goal, N) :-
    succ(N0, N),
    Goal,
    do_n(Goal, N0).
```

With this predicate:

```
?- do_n(format("foo\n"), 3).
foo
foo
foo
false.
```

It fails at the end, which is what your "working code" in the question does, too. You can for example do:

```
do_n(Goal, N) :-
    (   succ(N0, N)
    ->  Goal,
        do_n(Goal, N0)
    ;   true
    ).
```

This is all assuming that your question is about a) doing something (side-effect-ful) *n* times or b) recursion. If have something and you want that something *n* times, why not:

```
repeat_n(X, N, List) :-
    length(List, N),
    maplist(=(X), List).
```

So now:

```
?- repeat(foo, 3, List).
List = [foo, foo, foo].
```

Right there, you have it: `foo` printed three times.

Recursion is great when you have a recursive data structure, because you can define the recursive step and the final condition using pattern matching on the structure that you are reasoning about. Integers are not such a structure.

However, you can use something like library(clpfd) to get a bit further. For example:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

do_n(Goal, N) :-
        zcompare(Order, 0, N),
        do_n_(Order, Goal, N).

do_n_(=, _, _).
do_n_(<, Goal, N) :-
        N0 #= N - 1,
        Goal,
        do_n(Goal, N0).
```

This is now **not going to have any extra choice points**:

```
?- do_n(format("foo\n"), 3).
foo
foo
foo
true.

?- do_n(format("foo\n"), 0).
true.

?- do_n(format("foo\n"), -1).
false.
```

But you could as well have done:

```
do_n(Goal, N) :-
        length(L, N),
        do_n_(L, Goal).

do_n_([], _).
do_n_([_|L], Goal) :-
        Goal,
        do_n_(L, Goal).
```

You use the *non-negative integer* to make a list, and then use that list for the recursion. This is probably the most general solution:

```
?- do_n(format("foo\n"), 2).
foo
foo
true.
```

But also works with a free variable:

```
?- do_n(format("foo\n"), N).
N = 0 ;
foo
N = 1 ;
foo
foo
N = 2 ;
foo
foo
foo
N = 3 . % and so on
```

The bottom line is that in Prolog, you really need to understand what problem you are solving before deciding how to solve it. Every solution I have shown has its use in some context. I am certain there are other ways to do it. The other answer shows another way to do it.

(Note: there are examples of all of these techniques in much more detailed answers here on Stackoverflow. If anyone is willing to add links, you are most welcome to edit my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Just a few things to change:

```
printn(0,_).
printn(N,X):-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    writeln(X),
    printn(N1,X).
```

You need to have a different variable N1 since N is instantiated and also you need a base case for N=0 where you just add the clause `printn(0,_).` in order to return true.

Comment: @Boris, yes it does but since he is new in Prolog I wanted to give as simple as possible answer. I don't think that a predicate that it's doing right it's job should fail at the end, your first and last implementation are ideal.

Comment: Also another solution without choice points and returning true would be: printn2(N,X):-\+printn(N,X). where in printn(N,X) we have removed the clause printn(0,_). so it always fails and printn2/2 always succeeds without choise points.

Comment: Right. Note that `forall(Goal, SideEffect)` is itself implemented as `\+ (Goal, \+ (SideEffect))`. The good thing about doing it like this is `SideEffect` will be evaluated as many times as `Goal` succeeds, so you can express a "loop" without the need for a recursive predicate.

Comment: Sorry for spamming you with comments: the traditional way to do what `forall/2` does is to use the so-called "failure-driven loop". I am under the impression that `forall/2` does the same with a cleaner interface.

Comment: Not spamming, your comments are constructive and helpful, thanks again!